# Very large canvases in JavaFX2

Tags: canvas, javafx, javafx-2

My application has a very large Canvas contained by a ScrollPane.

At about 10 million pixels JavaFX starts throwing these null pointer exceptions during canvas operations:

```
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderBuf.validate(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.initCanvas(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderForClip(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderRectClip(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderClip(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.BaseNode.render(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.AbstractPainter.paintImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.prism.render.RenderJob.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I think the solution must be to virtualize the Canvas. I imagine this is conceptually similar to how ListView is implemented.

Please point me to any examples you may know of that are similar to this or any pages that may provide guidance. (Virtual and virtualized don't seem to be helpful keywords for googling this topic)

Thank you

Comment: Use a recent JavaFX; e.g. 8u20 has some bug fixes around this: [RT-36571 Re-enable DirectX 9Ex to avoid losing textures when surface lost](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-36571). See the related forum discussion: [Canvas Rendering Degrades Proportionally With Size?](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3549359) and the [ControlsFX GridView](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) (which, unlike the [eppleton TileEngine](http://jayskills.com/blog/2013/01/09/writing-a-tile-engine-in-javafx/), is not canvas specific).

Comment: These are good links. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We faced the same problem.
The explanation why it happens, is here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/3549359

We solved the problem bypassing the video card, using the following JVM parameter:

`-Dprism.order=sw`

You may want to increase heap memory as well using -Xmx because it will use much more memory.