# How to catch exceptions resulting from large canvasses in JavaFx?

Tags: java, canvas, javafx

Our app uses JavaFx Canvas. When users zoom in too much, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas$RenderBuf.validate(NGCanvas.java:213)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.initCanvas(NGCanvas.java:640)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderContent(NGCanvas.java:603)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderForClip(NGNode.java:2294)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderRectClip(NGNode.java:2188)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderClip(NGNode.java:2214)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.CacheFilter.impl_renderNodeToCache(CacheFilter.java:671)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.CacheFilter.render(CacheFilter.java:575)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.renderCached(NGNode.java:2358)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2044)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup.renderContent(NGGroup.java:235)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGRegion.renderContent(NGRegion.java:576)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.doRender(NGNode.java:2053)
at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGNode.render(NGNode.java:1945)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.doPaint(ViewPainter.java:477)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.ViewPainter.paintImpl(ViewPainter.java:323)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.PresentingPainter.run(PresentingPainter.java:91)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.RenderJob.run(RenderJob.java:58)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:125)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I've seen the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26226401/very-large-canvases-in-javafx2) and rigth now we're working on implementing the tiles, but is there any way to catch this exception (and, for example, force resizing)? Setting up the [defaultExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer (in JavaFX 12.0.2) sets its own thread uncaughtExceptionHandler.  My application has a defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler, but the thread's uncaughtExceptionHandler takes precedence.  Furthermore, this particular exception is being caught within a PresentingPainter try/catch block, where the stack trace is printed out to System.err.

Even if you could catch this exception, I do not see how you would use it to recover from the exception.  I observe that this error condition puts the rendering in a state where all future JavaFX rendering stops until the size of the canvas is reduced (e.g. zoom out) back to a size that fits within the available VRAM.  Your best bet is to prevent the canvas resize condition from causing the failure.